# Rails - creating a protected default category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to create a special category for my posts, which is default and has three distinct features:

1. It is assigned by default to every created post
2. It is assigned to the dependent posts upon the destruction of their parent category
3. It is protected from deletion by anyone

So the first point is easy to implement, thus I will not focus on it here

The second point is more puzzling. I am guessing that something like this should go into my Category model:

```
before_destroy :move_dependent_posts

def move_dependent_posts
  #no idea what goes here
end
```

Same problem with the third point: I have to check, if the category being deleted has the id of, say, 1, and after that throw an error?

```
before_destroy :protect_default_category

def protect_default_category
  return false if category.id(5) #won't work, of course
end
```

Comment: What's wrong with `Post.all` that you need a special category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point 2:

```
before_destroy :move_dependent_posts

def move_dependent_posts
  default_category = Category.default_category # find default category here
  posts.each { |post| post.update_attribute(:category, default_category) }
end
```

Point 3:

```
before_destroy :protect_default_category

def protect_default_category
  throw "Default category can't be deleted" if id == 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if all you want is a default category, I'm thinking about implementing it like this:

```
class Post
  def category
    super || Category.default
  end
end

class Category
  def default
    Category.find_or_create_by(name: 'Default')
  end
end
```

1. Every post with no `category_id` column is treated as within default category. So your don't need to worry about assigning category on creating post or removing category from post.
2. Default category **can** be destroyed. But every time you called `Category.default`, it's created again. So, it doesn't hurt actually, does it?

Answer (score 0):

For Point 2

```
before_destroy :move_dependent_posts

def move_dependent_posts
  @posts = Post.where(category: "Category to be Deleted")
  @posts.each { |post| post.update_attribute(:category, "Default Category") }
end
```